# Lookup, vlookup, or other

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am looking to search a column for a value, If present copy multiple columns within that row To another sheet....
IF find "x" return (name), (value), (phone)
Output would generate as many that match "x" as apply

Here is a link to the example form....https://www.dropbox.com/s/gafq6aut6h4s6oq/Example.xlsx?dl=0

This is driving me nuts... I know it has to be an easy thing that I am missing.

Answer (score 2):

Say our data is like:

[image]

In **E2** enter:

```
=IF(A2="x",1+MAX($E$1:E1),0)
```

and copy down:

[image]

Now the "good" rows are clearly marked sequentially.
In Sheet2 cell **A1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B1:B11,MATCH(ROW(),Sheet1!E1:E11,0)),"")
```

in **B1**:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C1:C11,MATCH(ROW(),Sheet1!E1:E11,0)),"")
```

in **C1**:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!D1:D11,MATCH(ROW(),Sheet1!E1:E11,0)),"")
```

and copy these downwards:

[image]

Comment: Followed all steps but the transfer of information does not happen in step 2,3,4.... any suggestions?

Comment: @MCTillsr  Sadly I would need to see your worksheets to be able to de-bug them.

Comment: This is just one of the examples but if you can help get this running I will be able to find the rest i believe. JAN would be the output sheet, QBR would be the data sheet

Comment: Not sure if the file showed.... Still new around this great place is there a way to send you a sample of what I am trying to do?

Comment: Upload the file (use Dropbox or a file sharing site like jumpshare), save the link that you get, and then EDIT your question to include the link to the uploaded file.

Comment: @Gary's Student I removed the IFERROR to find that I am getting a #N/A in one of my cells. Current Formula looks like this:   =INDEX(QBR!B2:B202,MATCH(ROW( ),QBR!E2:E202,0),QBR!B8:B202)   The Error Is in the Row() ... Shows a specific cell of A23 in the reference sheet (QBR)

Comment: GS was expecting your formula to be in row 1.  Try this:
`=INDEX(QBR!B2:B202,MATCH(ROW()-22,QBR!E2:E202,0))`

and note the change in the first range: It should start in B2.

Comment: @Bandersnatch Perfect I see my error